# How can I calculate the angle required for folding a cone using my opening angle

Tags: geometry

I want to calculate angle B (See picture) using the cone's top angle. The formula I'm using is `2π sin(0.5a)` (where A is the top angle). This appears to work but I'm unsure why.

[image]

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Comment: What is $a$? Where is the top angle?

Answer (score 0):

It’s correct

$$2\pi \cdot s \cdot sin(A/2)=sB$$

thus

$$B=2\pi \cdot sin(A/2)$$

NOTE B in radians

Comment: I know that it's correct, but I'd like to know why.

Comment: from the first equation, you set equal the length of the arch if the unfolded cone with the base circumference of the folded cone